# What's the difference between BaseButton<E> and BaseButton<E extends BaseButton<E>>?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have two formats of a class `BaseButton`:

```
public abstract class BaseButton<E extends BaseButton<E>> extends JXButton implements Initializer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 11L;

    public BaseButton() {
        LibraryLogger.initMessage(ClassUtils.getInstance().getResolvedClassName(this.getClass()));  
        initialize();
    }

    public abstract void initialize();
}
```

And:

```
public abstract class BaseButton<E> extends JXButton implements Initializer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 11L;

    public BaseButton() {
        LibraryLogger.initMessage(ClassUtils.getInstance().getResolvedClassName(this.getClass()));  
        initialize();
    }

    public abstract void initialize();
}
```

And I am creating child classes as:

```
public class GreenButton extends BaseButton<GreenButton> {

}
```

My question is what is the difference between these two types of generic notation?

Which one is better and why?

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the wood for the trees here... Am I right in thinking that your question is "What's the difference between  BaseButton<E> and BaseButton<E extends BaseButton<E>>"? Could you edit it to say so, if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you provided, it makes no difference.

However, when you start using the generic type `E`, that's when you'll start seeing a difference.
In the first example, `E` will have all the methods and members of `BaseButton`. So, if `BaseButton` has a method `int foo(String s)`, you will be able to say:

```
int bar(E arg) {
    arg.foo("test");
}
```

If you try the same thing with the second example, the compiler will report an error, because `E` implicitly extends `Object` and `Object` does not have a `foo` method.